# Find a document with the date-time before current date-time in Solr

Tags: solr

in Solr I have documents containing order dates, and I want to find the documents containing past order dates (before current date time).

I am using orderDate:[* TO NOW] query but it excludes the documents containing order date of  the same day.

Answer (score 1):

`[* TO NOW]` should actually work, but will wreck havoc with your caches. Try using `[* TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]` instead (which should give you midnight of the current day instead, and it won't change each second, so the performance will be far better).